# Is it idiomatic to say "... posts titles of which contain ..."

Tags: idiomatic-language

A [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345721/714660) says

> I am trying to find my posts **whose** titles contain *idiom* ...

I guess it's not grammatical to use "whose" there, as posts are not humankind.

I would have said

> I am trying to find my posts, titles **of which** contain *idiom* ...

I am worrying about whether it is idiomatic to say it that way.

[Google searching](https://www.google.com/search?bih=559&biw=1097&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&hl=en&sxsrf=ALeKk02iO0gK10xOUyqLZeG2vVBWXwrNqA%3A1585607436942&ei=DHOCXtyOOY7N-QaBg6LYDQ&q=%22posts%20titles%20of%20which%22&oq=%22posts%20titles%20of%20which%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQRzoECCMQJ1D5xUFY9d5BYJXkQWgAcAN4AIABtgGIAeUEkgEDMC40mAEAoAEBoAECqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjcxKCAoMPoAhWOZt4KHYGBCNsQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) gets only one hit.

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess it's not grammatical to use "whose" there, as posts are not humankind.

I disagree. This is called the [inanimate *whose*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inanimate_whose); Wikipedia points out that the word "whose" is used this way several times in the King James Bible and in Shakespeare's plays, and that the first known objection to this usage wasn't until 1764.

As a native English speaker, I think that "my posts whose titles contain this" sounds perfectly fine, while "my posts the titles of which contain this" sounds grammatical but very awkward. ("My posts titles of which contain this" is outright wrong; since there's no article before "titles", this phrase means the same thing as "my posts **some** titles of which contain this", which isn't what you're trying to say at all.)

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid the problem entirely by saying it differently. "I am trying to find my posts that have ____ in the title."